# calculating mean of multiple variables, Error: numerical expression has 56368 elements: only the first used

Tags: r

I have just started to use R, and this maybe a very basic question ---
I am trying to calculate the average value of multiple variables.
My variables are people's trust in different things measured on the scale of 1 to 5.

1. I started with:

```
intp.trust <- EU_value_study %>%
          summarise(average_intp.trust = mean(v32:v37))
```

and received a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In v32:v37 :
  numerical expression has 56368 elements: only the first used
2: In v32:v37 :
  numerical expression has 56368 elements: only the first used
```

I did get the result, but I think this result maybe wrong because of the previous warning?

```
> intp.trust
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  average_intp.trust
               <dbl>
1                  1
```

2. I then tried:

```
intp.trust <- EU_value_study %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  summarise(average_intp.trust = mean(v32:v37))
```

received error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `average_intp.trust`.
ℹ `average_intp.trust = mean(v32:v37)`.
x NA/NaN argument
ℹ The error occurred in row 8.
Backtrace:
```

3. I have also tried:

```
intp.trust <- EU_value_study %>%
  summarise(average_intp.trust = rowwise_mean(v32:v37))
```

also received error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `average_intp.trust`.
ℹ `average_intp.trust = rowwise_mean(v32:v37)`.
x could not find function "rowwise_mean"
Backtrace:
 1. EU_value_study %>% summarise(average_intp.trust = rowwise_mean(v32:v37))
 7. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 8. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
```

could someone help me with the error?
Shall I use mutate() instead of summarise()?
Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to use `c_across` in `rowwise`

```
library(haven)
EU_value_study %>%
  zap_labels() %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  transmute(average_intp.trust = mean(c_across(v32:v37), 
       na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Also, instead of `rowwise` with `mean` which should be slow, use the vectorized `rowMeans`

```
EU_value_study %>%
    zap_labels() %>%
    transmute(average_intp.trust = rowMeans(across(v32:v37), na.rm = TRUE))
```

NOTE: The `summarise` would work but the rowwise `mean` is not really a summarisation i.e. it will return the same number of rows as in the original data.  So, technically, it is a `mutate/transmute` (`transmute` - if we need only that column as output)

Comment: Hi, thank you! I still received error from your code which is ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `average_intp.trust`.
ℹ `average_intp.trust = mean(c_across(v32:v37), na.rm = TRUE)`.
x Can't use a name specification with non-vctrs types.
vctrs methods must be implemented for class `haven_labelled`.
See <https://vctrs.r-lib.org/articles/s3-vector.html>.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
 12. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 13. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call)) ```

Comment: @QianLee It works with a reproducible example `head(mtcars) %>% rowwise %>% transmute(average = mean(c_across(vs:gear))) %>% ungroup %>% pull(average)#
[1] 1.666667 1.666667 2.000000 1.333333 1.000000 1.333333`

Comment: @QianLee Ok, that is a different class i.e. you have some haven labeelled attributes

Comment: @QianLee can you try the update

Comment: Hi, so should I converting the haven labelled attributes to a factor or stripping the labels before I calculate mean?

Comment: @QianLee if it is a factor variable, you cannot apply mean anyway.  Try with `zap_labels` as in my update

Comment: @QianLee I meant i added the line `zap_labels` in the code

Comment: @QianLee if that doesn't help, can you provide a reproducible example with `dput(head(EU_value_study, 10))` as `dput` gives the exact structure of your data and it becomes easier to debug the issue

Comment: I have tried ```intp.trust <-EU_value_study %>%
  zap_labels(v32:v37)%>%
  transmute(average_intp.trust = rowMeans(across(v32:v37), na.rm = TRUE))  ``` but still received error ```Error in zap_labels(., v32:v37) : unused argument (v32:v37)```

Comment: @QianLee You don't need to use `zap_labels(v32:v37)`. i.e. `zap_labels` can take a full dataset.  Can you try my code as it is

Comment: @QianLee does it work?

Comment: Hi, I think I have got it. So I used ```intp.trust <-EU_value_study %>%
  summarise(average_intp.trust = mean(c_across(v32:v37), na.rm=TRUE))  ```, and the result is ```> intp.trust 
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  average_intp.trust
               <dbl>
1               2.07``` not sure why it succeed this time, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data looks like this

```
library(tidyverse)

n=100
df = tibble(
  id = rep(1:100, 50),
  var = rep(paste0("v",1:50), each=n),
  val = sample(1:5, 5000, replace = TRUE)
) %>% pivot_wider(id, names_from = var, values_from = val)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 51
      id    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8    v9   v10   v11   v12   v13   v14   v15   v16   v17   v18   v19   v20   v21
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     5     3     3     2     4     1     5     2     5     2     1     3     3     5     4     4     5     3     5     1     4
 2     2     5     4     1     3     3     4     3     4     3     3     2     4     5     4     2     5     4     3     4     2     1
 3     3     5     1     3     1     3     3     4     2     5     2     5     1     5     1     4     4     3     3     5     3     1
 4     4     3     1     1     1     4     5     2     1     2     4     5     3     1     4     1     5     5     1     1     1     4
 5     5     1     4     1     4     4     1     2     4     5     4     1     2     4     4     5     5     5     3     4     3     2
 6     6     2     5     5     2     1     2     4     3     4     4     5     3     3     4     2     4     1     2     1     5     5
 7     7     5     2     1     2     4     5     5     2     1     5     3     2     1     4     2     3     1     1     4     2     2
 8     8     3     3     1     3     2     1     4     1     4     4     2     5     3     2     3     3     1     3     4     4     4
 9     9     5     3     3     4     3     2     2     2     1     5     5     2     3     3     3     5     4     3     4     1     5
10    10     5     2     5     2     1     1     5     4     4     4     2     4     1     2     1     3     5     4     5     5     5
# ... with 90 more rows, and 29 more variables: v22 <int>, v23 <int>, v24 <int>, v25 <int>, v26 <int>, v27 <int>, v28 <int>, v29 <int>,
#   v30 <int>, v31 <int>, v32 <int>, v33 <int>, v34 <int>, v35 <int>, v36 <int>, v37 <int>, v38 <int>, v39 <int>, v40 <int>, v41 <int>,
#   v42 <int>, v43 <int>, v44 <int>, v45 <int>, v46 <int>, v47 <int>, v48 <int>, v49 <int>, v50 <int>
```

So we have 100 lines and 50 `v` variables.

If you need the average of the variables `v32: v37`do this

```
df %>% pivot_longer(v32:v37) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    intp.trust = mean(value))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      n intp.trust
  <int>      <dbl>
1   600       3.06
```

The `pivot_longer` function will turn your variables into two variables. See this example

```
df %>% pivot_longer(v1:v50)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5,000 x 3
      id name  value
   <int> <chr> <int>
 1     1 v1        5
 2     1 v2        3
 3     1 v3        3
 4     1 v4        2
 5     1 v5        4
 6     1 v6        1
 7     1 v7        5
 8     1 v8        2
 9     1 v9        5
10     1 v10       2
# ... with 4,990 more rows
```

Now just use `summarise`

```
df %>% pivot_longer(v1:v50) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    intp.trust = mean(value))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      n intp.trust
  <int>      <dbl>
1  5000       3.00
```